# Loop Through Categories in Custom Field

Tags: categories, functions

Specifically, I am using the `add_image_attachment_fields_to_edit` function. I have my declaration of label, input..

```
$form_fields["custom4"]["label"] = __("Custom Select");
$form_fields["custom4"]["input"] = "html";
```

But when I try to iterate through my categories for the select, I get errors, or an empty html select. So far I have..

```
$form_fields["custom4"]["html"] = "
<select name='attachments[{$post->ID}][custom4]' id='attachments[{$post->ID}][custom4]'>" .
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        return "<option value=$category>$category</option>";
    } . "
</select>";
```

Is it possible to run a foreach loop within the `$form_fields` assignment, how can I create an html select constructed with my category names?

Comment: [see `return` in php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: `echo` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're appending a foreach loop to a variable is not possible.

Try this:

```
$form_fields["custom4"]["html"] = "<select name='attachments[{$post->ID}][custom4]' id='attachments[{$post->ID}][custom4]'>";

foreach ($categories as $category) {
     $form_fields["custom4"]["html"] .= '<option value="$category">' . $category . '</option>';
}

$form_fields["custom4"]["html"] .= "</select>";
```

Comment: No error on this, but the media popup doesn't load. http://imgur.com/Y8wokq6

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information or the surrounding code?

Is the developer tools showing any errors in the console? And have you tried enabling developer mode to check if there are php errors?

Comment: No errors in chrome dev tools, the entirety of the code in my `functions.php` is http://pastebin.com/D0FzSkWC

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I see you're using the get_categories() function to retrieve all categories. That function is returning an array with category objects.

This means you have to edit the foreach loop, because $category is an object.

```
$form_fields["custom4"]["html"] .= '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '">' . $category->name . '</option>';
```

Have you enabled the debug mode in WordPress? It will show you errors in your php code. Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

---

I also think your save function isn't working. You're using 'restaurant', but your input has the name 'custom4'.